# PhantomJS and pjscrape - Failing on some multiple URLs

Tags: javascript, webkit, web-scraping, scraper, phantomjs

**Overview**

I am trying to create a very basic scraper with PhantomJS and pjscrape framework.

**My Code**

```js
pjs.config({
timeoutInterval: 6000,
timeoutLimit: 10000,
format: 'csv',
csvFields: ['productTitle','price'],
writer: 'file',
outFile: 'D:\\prod_details.csv'
});

pjs.addSuite({
title: 'ChainReactionCycles Scraper',
url: productURLs, //This is an array of URLs, two example are defined below
scrapers: [
    function() {
        var results [];
        var linkTitle = _pjs.getText('#ModelsDisplayStyle4_LblTitle');
        var linkPrice = _pjs.getText('#ModelsDisplayStyle4_LblMinPrice');
        results.push([linkTitle[0],linkPrice[0]]); 
        return results;
    }
]
});
```

**URL Array's Used**

This first array *DOES NOT WORK* and fails after the 3rd or 4th URL.

```js
var productURLs = ["8649","17374","7327","7325","14892","8650","8651","14893","18090","51318"];
for(var i=0;i<productURLs.length;++i){
  productURLs[i] = 'http://www.chainreactioncycles.com/Models.aspx?ModelID=' + productURLs[i];
}
```

This second array *WORKS* and does not fail, even though it is from the same site.

```js
var categoriesURLs = ["304","2420","965","518","514","1667","521","1302","1138","510"];
for(var i=0;i<categoriesURLs.length;++i){
  categoriesURLs[i] = 'http://www.chainreactioncycles.com/Categories.aspx?CategoryID=' + categoriesURLs[i];
}
```

**Problem**

When iterating through `productURLs` the PhantomJS `page.open` optional callback automatically assumes *failure*. Even when the page hasn't finished loading.

I know this as I started the script up while running an HTTP debugger and the HTTP request were still running even after PhantomJS had reported a a page load *failure*.

However, the code works fine when running with `categoriesURLs`.

**Assumptions**

1. All the URL's listed above are VALID
2. I have the latest versions of both PhantomJS and pjscrape

**Possible Solutions**

These are solutions I have tried thus far.

1. Disabling image loading `page.options.loadImages = false`
2. Settings a larger `timeoutInterval` in `pjs.config` this was not useful apparently as the error generated was of a `page.open` failure and NOT a timeout failure.

Any ideas?

Comment: As I just noted on GitHub, I can't reproduce the issue - I was able to retrieve the `productUrls` list without a problem. I don't think it's a Pjscrape problem - it sounds like a PhantomJS issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was caused by PhantomJS.
This has now been resolved.

I now use PhantomJS v2.0.

Comment: Fixed how? Which version of PhantomJs you used? (Having the same problem with 1.6 and the latest version compiled from git sources)

Comment: @Hzmy It would be more worthy to called an answer if you also said what solution you used instead of PhantomJS.

Comment: @rineez I just upgraded the PhantomJS binary to v2.0 and my code worked.

Comment: Oh! For me PhantomJS 1.9 is working well for pjscrape. 2.0 was showing too many compatibility problems with pjscrape current version.

Comment: In the code you posted with question: this line  `var results [];` looks wrong to me. I never seen such a syntax in js. Is that a valid syntax?

Comment: it's a typo. Should be: `var results = [];`